# Implementing project newsfeed for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am think about something like Github/Bitbucket news feed in main screen.

There are multiple users(tens or thousands) watching multiple projects(tens or hundreds). Each project would has it's latest update status message.

The combined result would looks like:

- Project A: issue #3 change from opened to closed
- Project B: @someuser commented on issue #231
- Project C: @anotheruser opened issue #1493
- Project B: @thirduser commented on issue #231

When using SQL, I would think about something like

```
select * from notifi where projId in (<user's watching list>)
```

But for GAE this is implemented as making multiple queries in the same time. This is not going to be efficient. And it won't work for users watching more than 30 projects (can not do more than 30 queries in the same time according to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference).

How could I implement something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a model that contains the project's list of changes and update that. Subscribe users to that, and everybody get's the same update, subtracting updates they made themselves before sending the update to the user. So one query per project, results send to all subscribed users. So you don't do the "select" on a user basis, rather a project.

Or just try *something* then optimise it using the available tools. And use [NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/)!